# How do I clear the bitmap each time before blitting?

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, bitmapdata

I'm very new to blitting, and I'm still trying to understand the process. In my `View` object, I have this in my constructor;

```
this.bcg = new BitmapData(800,600,false,0x000000);
this.canvas = new Bitmap(bcg);
```

Then I add it to the stage;

```
addChild(canvas);
```

Then inside my main game loop, I iterate through a nested array to blit copies of `rect`of type `BitmapData` objects;

```
if (array[i][j] !=0) {
        canvas.bitmapData.copyPixels(rect, rect.rect, new Point(i, j));
}
```

I thought perhaps I could do it by blitting by background back onto `canvas` before my loop;

```
canvas.bitmapData.copyPixels(bcg, bcg.rect, new Point(0, 0));
```

But that doesn't work. I've tried searching around for an answer for this, but it's very difficult to find any in-depth information on blitting in AS3.

What I'm trying to do is clear the bitmap of all the pixels I've blitting onto it, and start again with just my background, `bcg`. I tried doing this before my loop;

```
this.bcg = new BitmapData(800,600,false,0x000000);
this.canvas = new Bitmap(bcg);
```

But I ended up with a completely black screen, and none of my `rect` were being blitted onto `canvas`.

Comment: Does blitting your objects work? If that works, there's no reason why blitting your background image wouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple blitting example:

```
private var m_bg:BitmapData         = new BitmapData( 400, 300, false, 0xffff0000 );    // simple solid red colour
private var m_canvas:BitmapData     = new BitmapData( 400, 300, true, 0x00000000 );     // the canvas that we're drawing into
private var m_obj:BitmapData        = new BitmapData( 20, 20, false, 0xff00ff00 );      // simple green square
private var m_objDrawPos:Point      = new Point;                                        // where we'll draw our obj
private var m_objDir:Point          = new Point;                                        // the direction that our obj is moving in
private var m_objSpeed:Number       = 20.0;                                             // the speed of our obj

public function Main()
{
    // create the bitmap for our canvas and add it to the stage
    var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap( this.m_canvas );
    this.addChild( b );

    // set our initial direction
    this.m_objDir.setTo( 1.0, 1.0 ); // diagonal right

    // add our enter frame
    this.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, this._onEnterFrame );
}

private function _onEnterFrame( e:Event ):void
{
    // move our object by changing it's draw position
    this.m_objDrawPos.x += this.m_objDir.x * this.m_objSpeed;
    this.m_objDrawPos.y += this.m_objDir.y * this.m_objSpeed;

    // simple bounds change, to reflect the object
    if ( this.m_objDrawPos.x < 0 || this.m_objDrawPos.x + this.m_obj.width > this.m_canvas.width )
        this.m_objDir.x *= -1;
    if ( this.m_objDrawPos.y < 0 || this.m_objDrawPos.y + this.m_obj.height > this.m_canvas.height )
        this.m_objDir.y *= -1;

    // copy our this.m_bg - this will erase all previous changes
    // NOTE: depending on what your bg is, you can all use fillRect() if it's a solid colour
    // NOTE: passing new Point() as the destPoint, will mean that our bg will always be drawn
    // in the top-left of the canvas. As this never changes - you can keep this as a variable
    this.m_canvas.copyPixels( this.m_bg, this.m_bg.rect, new Point );

    // copy our object to its new position
    this.m_canvas.copyPixels( this.m_obj, this.m_obj.rect, this.m_objDrawPos );
}
```

What you need to know about blitting, is that it's the position passed in as `destPoint` that determines the top-left position of the `BitmapData` that you're blitting - think of it as the `x` and `y` of a normal `DisplayObject` - `(0,0)` will mean that it's drawn in the top left, while `(canvas.width - obj.width, canvas.height - obj.height)` will mean that it's drawn in the bottom right.

To make your life easier, create a simple class to store all this data for you. Something like:

```
public class BlitObj
{

    /************************************************************/

    private var m_bmd:BitmapData    = null; // our BitmapData graphics
    private var m_offset:Point      = null; // the offset (how we manage the reference point)
    private var m_drawPos:Point     = null; // our draw position for when we're blitting the object
    private var m_position:Point    = null; // the position of our object, in relation to the reference point

    /************************************************************/

    /**
     * The position of the BlitObj, in relation to the reference point
     */
    public function get position():Point { return this.m_position; }

    /**
     * The BitmapData graphics that we're going to blit
     */
    public function get blitGraphics():BitmapData { return this.m_bmd; }

    /**
     * The position to blit this BlitObj at (top-left corner)
     */
    public function get blitDestPos():Point { return this.m_drawPos; }

    /************************************************************/

    /**
     * Creates a new BlitObj
     * @param bmd The graphics for this BlitObj
     * @param offset The offset to our registration point
     */
    public function BlitObj( bmd:BitmapData, offset:Point = null )
    {
        this.m_bmd      = bmd;
        this.m_offset   = ( offset == null ) ? new Point : offset;
        this.m_drawPos  = new Point( -this.m_offset.x, -this.m_offset.y );
        this.m_position = new Point;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the position of the BlitObj (in relation to its reference point)
     * @param x The x position of the object
     * @param y The y position of the object
     */
    public function setPos( x:Number, y:Number ):void
    {
        this.m_position.setTo( x, y );
        this.m_drawPos.setTo( x - this.m_offset.x, y - this.m_offset.y ) ;
    }
}
```

One thing to watch for when blitting, and one this this class does, it handle the `offset`. When you provide a `destPoint` to the `copyPixels()` function, it's the position to place the top-left of your `BitmapData` before drawing it. Often, however, you want your object to have a different reference point that the top left (e.g, a circle will have its reference point in the middle). This lets you handle that.

```
// create our circle graphics with their registration point in the center
var circleBMD:BitmapData    = ...; // get the graphics for your circle
var circle:BlitObj          = new BlitObj( circleBMD, new Point( circleBMD.width * 0.5, circleBMD.height * 0.5 ) );
circle.setPos( this.stage.stageWidth * 0.5, this.stage.stageHeight * 0.5 ); // center it on the stage

// now you can draw it:
canvas.copyPixels( circle.blitGraphics, circle.blitGraphics.rect, circle.blitDestPos );
```

Comment: This is an excellent explanation. Thank you. The only part I don't quite understand is why you're setting m_drawPos in the constructor to negative m_offset.x and negative m_offset.y. Is that correct?

Comment: It's just to get the initial `m_drawPos` to be correct if we set an offset - imagine the circle where we want our reference point (and thus our position) to be the center. When we draw, we need to pass the position of the top-left corner of the BMD that we're drawing, which at position `(0,0)`, will be the negative offset (i.e. top left corner is always `position - offset`)

Comment: If it makes it any clearer, you can rename `m_offset` to `m_referencePoint`

Comment: I understand it now. I just had to follow it through logically. Blitting is very new to me. I'll see if I can write my own BMD wrapper similar to yours. Then I'll know I fully comprehend the process.

Comment: No problem; if you run into any hassle, just post another question on SO, or get in touch directly :)

Answer (score 0):

I know what I was doing wrong now.

This works;

```
this.bcg = new BitmapData(800,600,false,0x000000);
canvas.bitmapData.copyPixels(bcg, bcg.rect, new Point(0, 0));
```

I had to re-declare `bcg`, *then* blit it to `canvas`. Because my `rect` objects are being blitted onto `bcg`, correct? Which I'm creating a bitmap with using;

```
this.canvas = new Bitmap(bcg);
```

So canvas holds a reference to `bcg`?

Comment: This is creating a new `BitmapData` every frame, which is incredibly inefficient, and will eat up your memory in no time